# Is there a way to Bump/Flag questions that need updated answer(s)?

Tags: feature-request, flags, outdated-information

There is this: [How can I implement static methods on an interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9415257/210709)

Not long ago, all the answers in this post were correct. However, all the answers that state 'Not possible' are incorrect. I'm not suggesting any change to those answers be required (... maybe, not immediately).

Is there a way to bump/flag these questions for experts to update answers?

Otherwise ...I would suggest, however, a feature that allows questions to be bumped specifically to have updated information added. Maybe a flag is appropriate?

Comment: You have used the bounty feature before.

Comment: A solid first step in this process is to post a comment on those answers. The original answerers may even respond by updating their answers (but hopefully not with added *"Edit:"* or *"Update:"*. Rather with a sectioned answer with headlines like *"For C# 17.0 and later"*, *"For C# 13.0.87, patch 7863 through C# 16.01"* and *"For C# 12.0 and earlier"*).

Comment: @HansPassant: Okay. Didn't think about that.

Comment: I did a cursory scan through about 5 pages of questions to see if this was a duplicate.